# PHP SQL PDO Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

At the suggestion of many, I am learning PDO to perform a large PHP MySQL query.  What is wrong with my query?  The code is just one large form submission, and everyone recommends PDO over handcoding a large mysql query.

The query itself gives a complain from Dreamweaver but not from Zend Studio.  Could anything be wrong?

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="********"; // Mysql username
$password="********"; // Mysql password
$db_name="practice"; // Database name
$tbl_name="administration"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
//$dbc = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    try {  

      # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password); 

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage("Error Connecting to Database");  
        $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );  
    }  


mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//These variables stay the same and can be used as is in A PDO submission
$ac1=$_POST['ac1'];
$ac2=$_POST['ac2'];
$fan=$_POST['fan'];
$na=$_POST['na'];
$dh=$_POST['dh'];
//Initialization of variables is typical
$tolerance1=$_POST['tolerance1'];
$temptime1=$_POST['temptime1'];
$tolerance2=$_POST['tolernce2'];
$temptime2=$_POST['temptime2'];
$tolerance3=$_POST['tolerance3'];
$temptime3=$_POST['temptime3'];
$tolerance4=$_POST['tolerance4'];
$temptime4=$_POST['temptime4'];
$tolerance5=$_POST['tolerance5'];
$temptime5=$_POST['temptime5'];

$humidtolerance1=$_POST['humidtolerance1'];
$humidtime1=$_POST['humidtime1'];
$humidtolerance2=$_POST['humidtolerance2'];
$humidtime2=$_POST['humidtime2'];
$humidtolerance3=$_POST['humidtolerance3'];
$humidtime3=$_POST['humidtime3'];
$humidtolerance4=$_POST['humidtolerance4'];
$humidtime4=$_POST['humidtime4'];
$humidtolerance5=$_POST['humidtolerance5'];
$humidtime5=$_POST['humidtime5'];

$custnum = 0;
//Each parameter is bound to a number.
$STH->bindParam(1, $ac1);  
$STH->bindParam(2, $ac2);  
$STH->bindParam(3, $fan); 
$STH->bindParam(4, $na);  
$STH->bindParam(5, $dh);  
$STH->bindParam(6, $tolerance1);
$STH->bindParam(7, $temptime1);
$STH->bindParam(8, $tolerance2);
$STH->bindParam(9, $temptime2);
$STH->bindParam(10, $tolerance3);
$STH->bindParam(11, $temptime4);
$STH->bindParam(12, $tolerance4);
$STH->bindParam(13, $temptime4);
$STH->bindParam(14, $tolerance5);
$STH->bindParam(15, $temptime5);
$STH->bindParam(16, $humidtolerance1);
$STH->bindParam(17, $humidtime1);
$STH->bindParam(18, $humidtolerance2);
$STH->bindParam(19, $humidtime2);
$STH->bindParam(20, $humidtolerance3);
$STH->bindParam(21, $humidtime3);
$STH->bindParam(22, $humidtolerance4);
$STH->bindParam(23, $humidtime4);
$STH->bindParam(24, $humidtolerance5);
$STH->bindParam(25, $humidtime5);
$STH->bindParam(26, $custnum);

//Dreamweaver says there is an error here but Zend Studio does not.
# unnamed placeholders  
$STH = $DBH->("UPDATE $tbl_name WHERE custnum = $custnum (ac1, ac2, fan, na, dh, tolerance1, temptime1, tolerance2, temptime2, tolerance3, temptime3, tolerance4, temptime4, tolerance5, temptime5, humidtolerance1, humidtime1, humidtolerance2,  humidtime2, humidtolerance3,  humidtime3, humidtolerance4,  humidtime4, humidtolerance5,  humidtime5,) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
$STH->execute();  

//Send them back to the page they were at/
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Do you actually get any error outside of your IDE when testing?

Comment: I'd assume so, considering `$DBH->('...')` is bad grammar...

Comment: Yes, the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /hvac/admin/admin.php on line 84

Answer (score 10):

Well you're doing:

```
$DBH->("...");
```

instead of:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("...");
```

You're also using `$STH` uninitialized in your code (since it's `prepare` that initializes it and it's missing). You'd want to prepare the statement first, *then* bind parameters to it (not the other way around, like it is actually the case):

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("...");
$STH->bindParam(1, $ac1);  
$STH->bindParam(2, $ac2);
// ...
```

You can also just prepare it and pass an array to `PDOStatement::execute`:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("...");
$STH->execute(array($ac1, $ac2, ...));
```

Your MySQL query is also wrong, you're doing:

```
UPDATE table WHERE something = something (column1, column2) values (?, ?)
```

The `WHERE` is misplaced, and the `(column) VALUES (?)` syntax is the `INSERT` syntax, not `UPDATE`. You'd want to do this instead:

```
UPDATE table SET column1=?, column2=? WHERE something = something
```

Lastly, you should remove this:

```
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Comment: More complete answer than I gave.

Comment: Online tutorials have the bindings coming before parameter binds.  I'll put the STH initialization first though.  Is this better? [code]$STH = $DBH->prepare->("UPDATE administration SET ac1= ?, ac2= ?, fan= ?, na= ?, dh= ?, tolerance1= ?, temptime1= ?, tolerance2= ?, temptime2= ?, tolerance3= ?, temptime3= ?, tolerance4= ?, temptime4= ?, tolerance5= ?, temptime5= ?, humidtolerance1= ?, humidtime1= ?, humidtolerance2= ?,  humidtime2= ?, humidtolerance3= ?,  humidtime3= ?, humidtolerance4= ?,  humidtime4= ?, humidtolerance5= ?,  humidtime5= ? WHERE custnum = $custnum"); [/code]

Comment: @DanielUSAF: Well those tutorials are wrong. You can't bind parameters to a statement without preparing it first. You're still doing `$STH = $DBH->prepare->(...)`. It's `$STH = $DBH->prepare(...)`. You should also make `$custnum` a parameter, e.g.: `WHERE custnum = ?`.